# Array substitutions/pushes

Tags: arrays, ruby

thanks again for taking the time. I have  a question i'm working on for some schoolwork.

**Question:** I want to replace certain array values that are divisible by a certain number with a string. Now, I used the .flatten method and was wondering if I wanted parameters for

> x%3 == 0 && x%5 == 0

would that be possible with the method i'm currently using for case shown below.
Thanks!

```
a=(1..10000).to_a
b=["string1"]
c=["string2"]
d=["string3"]  #string3 is actually just a combination of string1+string2

a.map!{|x| x%3==0 ? b:x}.flatten!
a.map!{|x| x%5==0 ? c:x}.flatten!
a.map!{|x| x%3==0 && x%5==0 ? d:x}.flatten! #problem line.
puts a
```

Comment: Hint: the string `"fizz"` is not divisible by five.

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about. The values change in the iteration. so I can't actually find that value because it's changed to "string1" and "string2" already....

Comment: So...I need to set up a parameter with different arguments.. maybe this method isn't the right approach then...hmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order.

Since 15 has priority over both 3 and 5, your code should begin with 15.

`Divisible by 3 and by 5` is equivalent to being `divisible by 15`.

`b`, `c` and `d` should be strings and not arrays.

```
a = (1..10_000).to_a
b = 'string1'
c = 'string2'
d = b + c

a.map! { |x| x % 15 == 0 ? d : x }.flatten! 
a.map! { |x| x % 3 == 0  ? b : x }.flatten!
a.map! { |x| x % 5 == 0  ? c : x }.flatten!
puts a
```

It outputs :

```
1
2
string1
4
string2
string1
7
8
string1
string2
11
string1
13
14
string1string2
16
17
string1
19
string2
string1
22
23
string1
string2
26
```

You could also write :

```
a.map! do |x|
  if    x % 15 == 0 then d
  elsif x %  5 == 0 then c
  elsif x %  3 == 0 then b
  else x
  end
end
```

Comment: ugh... so simple. I figured out through messing around a bit more that the %3 & %5 argument became null after running the first two...didn't quite  make it all the way though Eric....thanks!